# How to handle continuous upgradable pgsql database

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, csv, python

I have a PGSQL database with several tables(20 million records each table and 100+ columns) which need to be updated(appending rows to the existing table) by several thousands rows almost every month. I have made thousands of views and materialized views from those tables.

What I am doing right now to update those tables--

1. Deleting the existing table- it also deletes associated views.
2. Now recreate the table with same name from csv using python 3.
3. Create those views from scratch.

My work flow is time consuming.. :(

I am using (PostgreSQL) 14.3
Any better(automated) solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Just insert the new rows into the table, then `REFRESH` the materialized views. Where is the trouble with that?